# How to reset a page before each Jasmine spec?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Suppose you have a form that manipulates the DOM on submission.

What is a good way to reset the DOM to the original state before each spec?

Comment: You could use HTML Fixtures from the `jasmine-jquery` extension. https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#html-fixtures. 
You could load the html content under test using  `loadFixtures` and clean up afterwards using `cleanUp`.

Comment: This seems weird because I want to set the page to the state when it is loaded. Why do I need a fixture for this?